# Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported

Tags: css, spring, spring-security

I want to use the fullcalendar library, using gulp and yarn this is the generated link tag:

But I'm getting this error in the console :

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css'
>   because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported
>   stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Why I'm getting this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Probably your server is misconfigured to serve files with a .css extension as `application/json` instead of `text/css`.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: @MustacheMoses I'm using tomcat with spring boot

Comment: Did you find the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 4):

In my case,  I found out that I had a typo in css file name. Thus I was trying to import an non existing file.

Answer (score 3):

You're app is serving *fullcalendar.css* with the **wrong** MIME type ('application/json') some how. So, my advise is to dig the problem trusting in the error message.

In my case, I was trying **Thymeleaf** and **WebJars** with spring-boot for the first time and following blindly some tutorial I added this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
  }
}
```

Also, my styles were defined in html as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" />
```

This way, "bootstrap.min.css" and others were given the very same error: *"Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported"*.

I still haven't broken down the reasons for this behavior, but as soon as I realized that spring-boot has an automatic configuration for WebJars, I removed that registration and everything started to work well.

**Note:** There are some similar tracks with "MIME type ('text/html')" and the reason is usually security filters not allowing the **css** files and redirecting to html login page. So, keep this in mind and check whether you have some kind of filter/redirect for this request.

Answer (score 2):

Directly put the URL in the browser and see if you can reach it.

For your case, give this url in the browser http://localhost/bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css

If you can't reach it, then you have wrong url in your code.

For my case, I had the css file in a directory named css, but in the code I wrote /plugins/css and was getting the same error.

Also, don't forget to give the type="text/css"

So, my code example below:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/app.css}">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Boot you will not even have to override `addResourceHandlers()`, just make sure to use `th:href` and point it to the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case in the css file
where was a reference to a map file

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap-datepicker.css.map */
```

that was not present.
I removed the reference to the source map and worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can trying using the relative path to your static content.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/app.css">
</head>
```