# When I run my Spring Boot Project with Thymeleaf, the browser won't load the css files but path for href and th:href is correct

Tags: html, css, spring, thymeleaf

so I read a lot of articles and threads about my problem, like these ones:

[Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263433/refused-to-apply-style-because-its-mime-type-application-json-is-not-a-suppo)

https://github.com/froala/angular-froala/issues/170

But none of the answers can actually help me so I am asking my own question.

The current situation is:

I have a Spring Boot Project using thymeleaf and I have an html file under resources/templates and I also do have a css under ressources/templates/css.

Here is the structure:

- src

  - main

    - resources

      - static

        - css

          - "my css file"
      - templates

        - "my html file"

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Welcome to Mreza Mladih</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/styles.css" th:href="@{../static/css/styles.css}">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
```

And after running the project, google chrome won't load the css file:

[Refused to apply style from...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTfQ9.png)

Furthermore:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {    
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                    "/registration**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/static/css/**",
                    "/static/img/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .permitAll();
        }
}
```

The funny thing about this is that my css actually is correct and it works!
I use intellij and the IDE has a preview feature for html files and it actually works.

It would be really great if someone can help and thanks to you!

Greetings from Germany

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot serves anything that is in `src/main/resources/static` at the root of your application.

So the URL to use to get the CSS with Thymeleaf should be `/css/styles.css`.

Edit your HTML file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/styles.css" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}">
```

In your security configuration, also use `/css` and not `/static/css`:

```
.antMatchers(
                    "/registration**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/css/**",
                    "/img/**").permitAll()
```

You can also use:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations())
         .permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/registration**",
                 "/img/**")
        .permitAll()
```

`PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()` includes `/css/*`, `/js/*`, `/images/*`, `/webjars/*` and `favicon.ico`.